# Wrap XmlNode with tags - C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<span>sometext</span>
```

and I want to wrap this XmlNode with another tag:

```
<p><span>sometext</span></p>
```

How can i achieve this. For parsing i use XmlDocument (C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this.

```
string xml = "<span>sometext</span>";
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
// If you have XmlNode already, you can start from this point
XmlNode node = xDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode parent = node.ParentNode;
XmlElement xElement = xDoc.CreateElement("p");
parent.RemoveChild(node);
xElement.AppendChild(node);
parent.AppendChild(xElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above "best answer" works if you don't care that the new "p" node ends up at the end of the parent. To replace it where it is, use:

```
string xml = "<span>sometext</span>";
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
// If you have XmlNode already, you can start from this point
XmlNode node = xDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlElement clone = node.Clone();
XmlNode parent = node.ParentNode;

XmlElement xElement = xDoc.CreateElement("p");
xElement.AppendChild(clone);
parent.ReplaceChild(xElement, node);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "p", "") of XmlDocument.

Then append the old node to the new one with the AppendChild method