# Wrap Xmlnode with <b> tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following:

```
            XmlNode catchword = doc.CreateElement("CATCHWORDS");
            XmlNode subjectindex = doc.CreateElement("SUBJECT_INDEX");
            subjectindex.InnerText = DropDownList6.SelectedValue;
            catchword.AppendChild(subjectindex);
```

This is the output:

```
    <CATCHWORDS>
      <SUBJECT_INDEX>ADMINISTRATIVE LAW</SUBJECT_INDEX>
    </CATCHWORDS>
```

But i want to output these instead:

```
    <CATCHWORDS>
      <b><SUBJECT_INDEX>ADMINISTRATIVE LAW</SUBJECT_INDEX></b>
    </CATCHWORDS>
```

How i can achieve this?

I try to follow [Wrap XmlNode with tags - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281140/wrap-xmlnode-with-tags-c-sharp), but did not understand.

Can someone give example based on my code?

Comment: haha sorry i didnt realized, yea </b>

Comment: i ady found solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument` - it's a much more modern API, and far nicer to use as a result.

Your current code would be this:

```cs
var element = new XElement("CATCHWORDS",
    new XElement("SUBJECT_INDEX", DropDownList6.SelectedValue)
);
```

And to amend to wrap that in `b`:

```cs
var element = new XElement("CATCHWORDS",
    new XElement("b",
        new XElement("SUBJECT_INDEX", DropDownList6.SelectedValue)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put HTML tags inside XML.
If you want to put HTML tags inside XML, you have to encode them as entities.

```
subjectindex.InnerText = "<b>"
+ DropDownList6.SelectedValue + "</b>";
```

Comment: Did you try this yourself? IMHO, `.InnerText` will already care about escaping entities as needed, so `"<b>" + ... + "</b>"` is sufficient. You already escaped it twice and `.InnerText` will escape it a third (!) time.

Comment: this one output: 
<CATCHWORDS>
      <SUBJECT_INDEX>&lt;b&gt;ADMINISTRATIVE LAW&lt;/b&gt;</SUBJECT_INDEX>
</CATCHWORDS>